# Best way to run 40 lan cables in loft style office

Tags: code-compliance, data-wiring, cabling, planning

I have a project to run around 40 lan cables in loft style office. The office don't have any conduit attached to ceiling at all. The location of RJ45 Jacks is multiple.
***I wonder what is the best nice way to run all this cables to multiple locations in tight budget?*** I was thinking about floor corners (how to attach and protect it?) - but the 40 cables seems pretty big to hide it. J-Hooks and wall - there is a doors, windows and columns, I doubt it will look good. Was thinking to run them attached in center of ceiling, and here is a questions:
1) Should I put it in conduit by code or can run just tied all together set of cables.
2) Should I attach it close to ceiling or just suspend it? If so - how?
Here is a picture of the office:

[image: Office picture]

And here is my plan,

[image: plan]
So center line is like 40 cables and each branch from center line have like 4-10 cables. Was thinking about plastic wiremold, but can't find so thick to have 4-10 or 40 cables inside. The pipes you see it is fire sprinkler pipes.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about installing infrastructure in a commercial property, not about improving a home. In offices, the usual solution is to install metal cable trays under the ceiling. Usually concealed behind a false ceiling (i.e. a suspended ceiling, using ceiling tiles)

Comment: Thank you for your reply RedGrittyBrick, this is diy project and about improving the office space for my close friend, so basically for me it is same as I am helping to my friend improve his home. Originally he had a suspended ceiling with tiles, but he spend a lot of time to took it out to create "loft style" space, so proposal to put the title back will not work for him.

Comment: I agree, it's in the ballpark.  This could come up for a serious geek with home theater and/or a lot of connected gadgets in a nice man-cave and dislikes or can't use WiFi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't want conduit, as you'd need a huge pipe to fit 40 cables.  Instead, the common solution is to use cable tray.

It's available from many manufacturers, in many sizes, styles, and colors. Follow the mounting, and installation instructions for the particular product you choose.